# CSS не работает свойство list-style в дочернем селекторе, проблема наследования

Tags: css

Задача выделить по разному категории и подкатегории, свойство list-style-image и list-style-position не применяются в данном примере. Второй день ломаю голову над этим. Если использовать селектор тэга, то все работает, с селектором класса, подозреваю что тоже. С идентификатором такой номер не проходит. При этом подкатегории наследуют стили родителя, как этого избежать?

```css
#catalog > li > a {
 list-style-image: url(../img/li1.jpg);
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #ccc;
 list-style-position: inside;

}
```

```html
                <ul id="catalog">
                    <li><a href="#">Категория A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Категория Б</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Категория В</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Категория Г</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Категория Д</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Категория Е</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Категория Ж</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не применяются так как тэг `a` не елемент списка, а стили вы вешаете на него.

```css
#catalog>li {
  list-style-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50/FFFF00');
  list-style-position: inside;
}

#catalog ul > li {
  list-style-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50/FF0000');
  list-style-position: inside;
}

#catalog>li>a {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul id="catalog">
  <li><a href="#">Категория A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Категория Б</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Категория В</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Категория Г</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Категория Д</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Категория Е</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Категория Ж</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

вы применяете к ссылкам свойства применимые к элементам списка, тут или делать ссылки элементами списка вон так:

```
#catalog > li > a {
    list-style-image: url(https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/b9a33efa-ee8f-4930-a804-104ea986e329_1.8fe8323aab0af9009a5ffaff236b3e2e.jpeg?odnHeight=30&odnWidth=30&odnBg=ffffff);
    display: list-item;
}

#catalog > li > ul >li >a {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-image: url(https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/b9a33efa-ee8f-4930-a804-104ea986e329_1.8fe8323aab0af9009a5ffaff236b3e2e.jpeg?odnHeight=30&odnWidth=30&odnBg=ffffff);
}


<ul id="catalog">
                    <li><a href="#">Категория A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Категория Б</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Категория В</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Категория Г</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Категория Д</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Подкатегория 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Категория Е</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Категория Ж</a></li>
                </ul>
```

или делать это через псевдоэлементы :before,:after

http://htmlbook.ru/css/list-style-image — справочник там написано к каким элементам применяется данное правило.

Ну или лучше будет просто применять правила не к ссылке а к элементу списка как это и задумано.